# How do I generate random numbers and match it to a button click?

Tags: android

I have a UI with 9 image buttons with images of numbers from 1 to 9..I have a button listen which on click should play mp3 files (of number between 1 to 9) randomly on each click.I should have 5 such random mp3 files playing when i click the listen button 5 times.Problem is "i have to match the randomly generated mp3 files with the image button containing the image of correct number how do i do this...because only randomly generated are the mp3 files while the image buttons are not randomly shuffled...there remain static in their position....please help me...

Comment: Please share your code. We cannot be much help without it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of code as a modeling tool like clay or building block.  If you craft it, it will exist.  So what you really need, is an informational construct that matches what you are trying to do.  So you could theoretically create a class that contains a reference to a button id, image and an mp3 file.  When this object is created, generate the button ID randomly in the constructor, then you can write a function that writes one of these objects to the UI (creates the button, assigns the objects image, etc).  Then when someone clicks a button, all you need to do is look for the object with the same id as your button, and get the mp3 or image back out of it.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` of the listen generate random numbers using below code

```
var=(int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)    //math.random will return integer values
```

-now your variable will have random no between your max and min value i.e 1-9

-you can use `switch case` as below
and let the image button remain as it is...if only randomly generated are mp3 files just loop through and select file randomly again.

```
switch (var)
{

case 1:
      //your code
      break;
. 
.
. 
default:
     //your code
     break;      

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much...it is working but some times when i click the wrong button for an mp3 randomly generated,it is showing correct!!what to do??not all times..here is my code..

Comment: track your generated random no then...check whether it is in specified range or not...if you find this useful upvote or accept this as answer